# Can I keep concentration on a spell and an ability that works like concentration?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, concentration

I'm playing a ranger with the astral drifter background.

The background gives me the magic initiate feat and I took hex, a concentration spell.

The ranger has the optional feature of favored foe that allows them to do extra damage on a hit, this is an ability and not a spell, it states on the description: "as if you were concentrating on a spell".

Is my character able to use both at the same time or no? The wording on favored foe says it works like concentration but not that it takes your concentration. To me it works by wording but not by logic. Is there any clarification on RAI or a specification on this rules interaction?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### You cannot concentrate on the class feature and a spell at the same time

If you are concentrating "as if you are concentrating on a spell", all the rules apply. This includes (from the [Basic Rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Duration)):

> The following factors can break concentration:
>
> - **Casting another spell that requires concentration.** You lose concentration on a spell if you cast another spell that requires concentration. You can't concentrate on two spells at once.

As soon as you cast *hex*, your concentration on Favored Foe would end.